# Connect a button to the edit change form Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Am having a list of items, and it has a top button called **ADD CUSTOMER PROFILE**, so what I want to do is connect the same button at the top of the details page (Where I edit the data) in Django admin page after clicking on any of the items, below is the screenshots  :

**Listing of items page :**

[image]

**Details page :**

[image]

The button is located in the templates/admin/items/change_list.html :

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n static admin_list %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
  <div id="react-create-customer-profile"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Then, the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would override in the `Details page`.

See this for an example - [How to add custom action button in Django admin form and post the information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616273/how-to-add-custom-action-button-in-django-admin-form-and-post-the-information)

So, add the templates to the class that inherits the `admin.ModelAdmin` and extend it in the template, e.g.,

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
    <button> Your Custom Button </button>
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">
{% endblock %}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897388/django-how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-admin-change-form-page-that-executes-an-ad) should also help.

Comment: I already have a template in the `admin.ModelAdmin` class, what can I do to have.2 of them ?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris this is probably what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476128/how-can-i-have-two-modeladmin-of-the-same-model-in-django-admin